# Minimal Oracle DDL to bump DBA_OBJECTS.LAST_DDL_TIME

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm using an external tool that scans tables in my database. It uses `dba_objects.last_ddl_time` to determine which tables have been scanned. Obviously, this strategy does not work if the table data is modified in between scans so sometimes I have to help it...

I need a way to "bump" the Last DDL time without actually changing anything.
I'm looking for the simplest possible instant DDL statement that can be executed on any table, knowing just the table name.
I have sysdba privileges.

**Edit**:
For example, I can use `comment on table xxx is 'Boom';` but then I lose the original comment. I know how to fix this, but then it is no longer an small and easy statement I can quickly time in sql*plus

Comment: Why not just keep track of scan in a separate table?

Comment: I'm not the programmer of the tool... I'm the poor user :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `LOGGING/NOLOGGING` is pretty fast (though not instant).

If you set the `LOGGING` attribute back to itself, it will notch the `LAST_DDL_TIME` without making any real change to the table.  This example below tries to touch every table except sys tabels (presumably you'd want more limits here)

```
BEGIN
  FOR TABLE_POINTER IN (SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, DECODE(LOGGING,'YES','LOGGING','NOLOGGING') DO_LOGGING 
                        FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE OWNER NOT IN ('SYSTEM','SYS','SYSBACKUP','MDSYS' --etc. other restrictions here
                        ))
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('ALTER TABLE %s.%s %s',TABLE_POINTER.OWNER, TABLE_POINTER.TABLE_NAME, TABLE_POINTER.DO_LOGGING);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**EDIT:** The above wouldn't work with temp tables.  An alternative such as setting `PCT_FREE` to itself or another suitable attribute may be preferable.  You may need to handle `IOT`s, `Partitioned Tables`, etc. differently than the rest of the tables as well.

Comment: This works. We have no temporary tables and all tables in this schema are required to have logging. So i can simply type "alter table xxx nologging; alter table xxx logging" whenever I need to nudge the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @Ronnis Good to hear.  I had added another update about potential conflict with cascading partitions, iots, etc. as well but I'm glad if this schema went clean in a straight shot.